# Remove all before last ":" in Terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, text-processing, hashsum

I have millions of lines with these  2 formats all in one merged file.

```
hash:salt:password
hash:password
hash:hash
```

What I want is just keep the password, then remove duplicates and after remove duplicates remove all lines that contain a string.

Sample file:

```
695ecf9185cb3f1a415821ddd69cc6be:4e85e5:671014
695f1cc6765cac14c3478505c300ec9a::0d7b9438b5ea5d9b6883b43a656357d9775688
695f50345da6811b712ad3d08ac107cf::54dbf42fdafabe13e64c1eb7c7813e52b16188
695fe18dfdf073769841193ca98aaea3::405d98ab893b610144bf4645e6c132cb5eaf12
6960138fc7d1e2f9ec1c3df49ea72172::d7698e6198301e4a6df04d8b087a197a3d72f5
696073574b563bcfbf44a13a2848484a::9f3d22ab9249f9a05f9a7854f0ce2c6017cad2
6960a12e5357adbef3cb9df2d0ecd9c7::ca5fad391e11eb7e860bb1102528e77eb88474
6960c557ff9cc514771d3e6d855f3f8d::f3431013320c3864519b4c9269b524025bb6cf
69613e3ad5e001cdb1321012a554785e:c20954:214828
cc81a83d6bcd13b89519c45c7f5a1cfd:Refineryhotel2
696fb1bf9f806c772ac44882a28c2888:ca28a5:8561535
696fbe253ff887d5725d2438387b3bc1::60eb49f1f213fcc2f959edfec4feed89031747
696ffadc81d15371b88815c8394329a9:e5ad83:123hacker
6970031dffaac00607ce7663fa916686:4c4ba0:8109201
69706a943cc96169919476026a7de70c:ebd0af:0611314
69709651482c9e5c44c222aed4ece9aa::7a626fc07ccceb9b11c35c55941b2b5eb082c5
```

Expected output:

```
671014
214828
Refineryhotel2
8561535
123hacker
8109201
0611314
```

Comment: I count three formats, not two (and [in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/466441/remove-all-before-last-in-terminal#comment849382_466447) you also mention `hash:salt`). How would you distinguish the second form from the third?

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re asking for.  Please (1) try harder to clearly explain what you want, and (2) give some examples of input and output.  … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … …  You say “I have … one merged file.  …  What I want is … remove all lines that contain a string.”  It almost sounds like `cat /dev/null` will give you the result you describe.  … … … … … … …  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Remove all before last “:” in Terminal

Try this,

```
awk -F ':' '$2 != ""{print $NF}'  file

671014
214828
Refineryhotel2
8561535
123hacker
8109201
0611314
```

- will print only the text after the last `:` if the second field is not null.

Answer (score 0):

With your new sample data (that don't contain duplicates), try

```
awk -F: '$2 != "" {print $3}' file
671014
214828

8561535
123hacker
8109201
0611314
```

What do you mean by "contain a string"? Can't be inferred from your sample.

If that `Refineryhotel2` line is NOT an artefact ( it's the only one with just two fields), try

```
awk -F: '$3 == "" {print $2; next}; $2 != "" {print $3} ' file
671014
214828
Refineryhotel2
8561535
123hacker
8109201
0611314
```